# PHP syntax error with T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Tags: php

I am facing a syntax error problem in PHP. Appreciate if someone can help me understand what is going wrong here.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in:

The line causing this issue is:

```
if ($custom_logo){
     echo '#logo a { background: url(''.$custom_logo.'') left center no-repeat; }';
}
```

Comment: issue is in string concatenation correct that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use escape char when you want to use 2 times single quote...

```
if ($custom_logo){ echo '#logo a { background: url(\''.$custom_logo.'\') left center no-repeat; }'; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using **heredoc** is another approach, be sure LOGO_CSS is the first text on the line, no leading whitespace.

```
if (!empty($custom_logo)){
     echo <<< LOGO_CSS
#logo a { background: url('$custom_logo') left center no-repeat; }
LOGO_CSS;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc